# Swift property override not working

Tags: properties, swift, ios8, overriding

When I try to override a property I get an error "can not override mutable property with read-only property"

I have provided get and set in the super class.

```
class Card {
    var contents:String {
        get {
            return self.contents
        }
        set {
            self.contents = newValue
        }
    }
    init() {
        self.contents = ""
    }
}
```

Here is my Subclass where I am trying to override the "contents" property.

```
class PlayingCard: Card {
    override var contents:String { //<-- this is where I get the build error
        get {
            var rankStrings:Array<String> = PlayingCard.rankStrings()
            return rankStrings[Int(self.rank)] + self.suit
        }
    }
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 33):

If the property you're overriding has both a getter and a setter, you need to provide both in your subclass as well.  Here's the [relevant part from the Swift language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-XID_300) (emphasis mine):

> You can present an inherited read-only property as a read-write
>   property by providing both a getter and a setter in your subclass
>   property override. **You cannot, however, present an inherited
>   read-write property as a read-only property.**

If you're not doing anything special with the value, then you'll typically want to pass the value being set on to the base class:

```
set {
    super.contents = newValue
}
```

You could also just discard the value with an empty setter (although I can't think of a good reason to do this offhand):

```
set { }
```

---

I also wanted to point out that you have an infinite loop in the `contents` property in your `Card` class. When you you do this:

```
get {
    return self.contents
}
```

You're actually just calling that same getter again, creating an infinite loop; you're doing the same with the setter. Swift doesn't create ivars for your properties automatically like Objective-C did, so you need to create them yourself. A more appropriate way to create that property would be to do something like this:

```
class Card {
    private var _contents: String
    var contents: String {
        get {
            return _contents
        }
        set {
            _contents = newValue
        }
    }
    init() {
        _contents = ""
    }
}
```

However, since you're not doing anything other than setting and returning `_contents` in your setter and getter, you can simplify it down to this:

```
class Card {
    var contents: String = ""
    init() {

    }
}
```

***Note:** `contents` might also be a good candidate for using an optional (`String?`) and setting it to `nil` rather than initializing it to an empty string.*

Answer (score 4):

The compiler error message is fairly straightforward: `Card`'s `contents` property is **mutable**, which is to say it has a `set` method in addition to the `get` method.

Your override only adds a `get` method, you need to add a `set` method too.

I think this is what you want:

```
set(newValue) {
    rankStrings[Int(self.rank)] = newValue;
}
```

Comment: `newValue` is the default, right? So you can just use `set {`, I think