# Is it possible to change MKAnnotation Coordinates without knowing variable name?

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I appreciate the question might seem odd but basically I am adding annotations to the map after pulling coordinates from a backend database. The amount of annotations being added vary depending on the user.

```
let details = Annotation(title: "\(userName)",
                                         locationName: "",
                                         coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:convertLat!, longitude: convertlon!))

                self.mapView.addAnnotation(details as MKAnnotation)
                self.mapView.selectAnnotation(details, animated: true)
```

The trouble I am having is I would like to update the coordinates of the 'details' annotation at specific intervals but I am unable to access the 'details' annotation because of course it is out of scope.

Is it possible, for example, to access an annotation through its title name and change its coordinates accordingly?

The other alternative is to remove all annotations and recreate them with the updated coordinates but this is something I am trying to avoid.

It's probably worth noting that for a number of reasons I can't just simply create the details annotation outside off my methods.

Thanks.

**UPDATED**
So I'm trying a slightly different approach that looks like this:

```
for annotation in mapView.annotations as [MKAnnotation] {

        if (annotation as AnyObject).title == "Title of annotation"   {

           annotation.title = "Change to something else"

    }
}
```

However I am unable to change the title as Swift is telling me it's a 'get only' property and I don't understand why.

Adding annotation to the mapView:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

   // if (annotation is MKUserLocation) { return nil }

    let reuseID = "icon"
    var v = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseID)

    if v != nil {

        v?.annotation = annotation

    } else {

        v = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        v?.image = snapShotImage
        v?.canShowCallout = true
}

 return v
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Create subclass of `MKAnnotation`.

```
class CustomAnnotation: MKAnnotation {
    var _title: String = "Title of annotation"
    override var title: String {
        get {
            return _title
        }
        set {
            self._title = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Now when create annotation using your custom class.

```
let details = CustomAnnotation(title: "\(userName)",
                                         locationName: "",
                                         coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:convertLat!, longitude: convertlon!))
```

As you have getter and setter methods for title  property, now you can update the specific or all annotations (as you did using for-in loop;as stated in your question).

Comment: Thanks pkc456. I had already created a custom class so tried your approach of trying to add the 'get' and 'set' but am getting the error:
Property does not override any property from its superclass.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26112342/988169) to solve override problem.

Comment: The `CustomAnnotation` class is conforming to the `MKAnnotation` protocol not subclassing a superclass, which is why the compiler states that the `title` property is not overriding a superclass property.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the structure of the source class that holds the coordinates, you could create a class that contains both the source object and the created MKAnnotation. This class will use KVO via `addObserver` to observe any changes in the source coordinates and then apply them to the annotation: the same could be done for title/subtitles. Add the created annotation to the map as normal. Make sure that instances of the above class are retained by the view controller that owns the mapView so ARC doesn't reclaim everything!

Assuming you can still access and update the source, the UI will look after itself.

Comment: Thanks for replying pbc. I think I may have another way to update the annotation (see my updated post) - I feel I'm very close but just unable to change the property!

Answer (score 2):

You don't edit the annotation, you replace it. Ideally you'd keep a reference to the annotation so you can just remove it and then create and add a new one (and update the reference to that new annotation). If you don't want to do that for some reason then you can use your loop to find the correct annotation to remove and then create and add the new one.

Comment: Thanks Wain but as far as I understand you can just do: var newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate I don't want to remove all the annotations and add them to the map because it flickers and causes overhead.

Comment: you don't need to remove all, just that one. the coordinate is read-only on the annotation.

Comment: If I create a variable:annotation, outside of my methods I can access and change the coordinates by using the example in my response above, it's not read only. The thing is, all my annotations are updated at the same time so removing and adding them is not an option. I just want to change their coordinates and they will jump to the correct position on the map.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your hesitation to remove and replace all of the annotations, but now that you have identified the specific annotation in question, why not just delete, recreate, and re-add that one inside the for loop you're showing:

```
let replacement = annotation
replacement.title = "Change to something else"
self.mapView.addAnnotation(replacement)
mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. The issue I have is that all the annotations will be updated at the same time so in an ideal world I'd just like to update their details.

Comment: Understood, though I think you are stuck there since the title and subtitle are read only so the data structure used in mapView probably couldn't support a change if you could get to it.  If you do find a way please post it back here as I'd find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the annotations to your own `Annotation` class rather than the `MKAnnotation` protocol:

```
if let annotations = mapView.annotations as? [Annotation] {
  for annotation in annotations {
    if annotation.title == "Title of annotation"   {
      annotation.title = "Change to something else"
    }
  }
}
```

The `MKAnnotation` protocol only specifies a getter for the `title` property, which is why casting to an `MKAnnotation` doesn't let you change the title.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. Could you possibly elaborate or give an example? I'm presuming your suggestion could give me the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: I think the new approach you suggested in the update section of your question should work. The code in my answer rewrites your code to cast the annotations to your Annotation class so you'll be able to set the title of the annotations to a new value.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - FIRED 2 & 3 are never called.
`print("FIRED")
        if let annotations = mapView.annotations as? [Annotation] {
            print("FIRED 2")
            for annotation in annotations {
                
                print("FIRED 3")
                if annotation.title == "Title of annotation"   {
                    annotation.title = "Change to something else"
                }
            }
        }
    `

Comment: Are all the annotations you're adding to the map of class Annotation?

Comment: Yep. My original post shows how I'm adding the annotations which is my Annotation class.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help further, Chris. The code in my answer works in a playground. I hope you can solve your problem.

Comment: It might be an issue with the way I am adding the annotation to the map but I don't really see why. I have added my code for adding annotations to the map in my original post.